# hibernate many-to-many association with extra column apart from foreign key

Tags: hibernate

I have a many-to-many association between two tables, 
and the association table has some extra columns. 
What kind of mapping should I use?
can any one lead to the online example for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate – Many-to-Many example – join table + extra column using hibernate mapping file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438017/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-using-hibernate-map)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should write separate class for such association.

But if this columns are used by some other application and you can ignore it then just ignore it.